# Branch Cuts Rectangle

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry, branch-cuts

Define the function $$F(w)=\int\limits_0^w \frac{d\xi}{\sqrt{(1-\xi^2)(1-k^2\xi^2)}}$$

I would like to prove this map takes the upper half plane $\mathscr{H}$ to the rectangle $\mathscr{R}$.

The function has points of singularities are $\xi=\pm 1/k, \pm 1$ for $k\in (0,1)$ and we know that the roots of the function are -1/2, so we are rotating intervals by $\pi/2 $ (or $-\pi/2$). How do I show explicitly that this happens? ie, is there a way to traverse the real line and show that my boundaries of $\mathscr{H}$ map to $\mathscr{R}$ in the way we have described?

Furthermore, if I reflect $\mathscr{H}$ over the real line, with branch cuts from $(-\infty, -1)$ and $(1,\infty)$, how do I show what happens if I take $\xi=\xi_0+re^{i\theta}$ for $\xi_0=1$ and rotate $\xi$ for $\theta\in(0,2\pi)$?

Answer (score 0):

It is the Jacobi form of the elliptic integral of the first kind (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral)

This mapping from $\mathscr{H}$ to $\mathscr{R}$ is a particular case of Schwarz-Christoffel mapping (http://mathfaculty.fullerton.edu/mathews/c2003/SchwarzChristoffelMod.html), due to the decomposition of the denominator into

$$k(z+1)^{1/2}(z-1)^{1/2}\left(z+\frac1k\right)^{1/2}\left(z-\frac1k\right)^{1/2}$$

The Schwarz-Christoffel "lecture grid" *proves* that, looking at:

- the exponents: the "turning angles" are all $+\frac{\pi}{2}$, because of exponents $\frac{1}{2}$.
- the roots: the points where these turns occur are $\pm1,\pm \frac1k.$

Comment: This is good information, but I want to formally calculate why this is true. For example I'd like to take the branch cut $(-\infty, -1]$ and $[1, \infty)$ and show that the rotation of some z around the point 1 will yield the same branch as rotating z around the point -1. I know for z=1, I will rotate $z=Re^{i\theta}$ where $\theta\in(0,2\pi)$. However for z=-1 $\theta$ varies in $(-\pi,\pi)$. How do I show this?

Comment: I thought it was a full proof...

Comment: Maybe I'm not asking my question clearly enough... I'll edit what I have above and hopefully this will clarify.